# Make extra variables for max, min and average in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, max, average

Here, I made a `data` as simple as possible. `id` means the personal id number.
In `yearmonthweek` column , `2012052` means 2nd week of May,2012.
`Wt` means weight and `Ht` means height.

`data` looks like this:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 yearmonthweek=c(2012052,2012052,2012052,2012053,2012053,2012051,2012052,2012052,2012052,2012052),
                 Wt=c(61,60,NA,NA,NA,63,62,62,NA,63),
                 Ht=c(173,174,174,175,NA,173,174,173,173,174))
```

I want to make this data weekly basis for each `id`. That is, within each `id`, the values of `yearmonthweek` cannot be duplicated. Also, I want to make  extra columns to represent average,max, and mean . My expected output looks like this:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),
                 yearmonthweek=c(2012052,2012053,2012051,2012052),
                 Wt_avg=c(60.5,NA,63,62.333),
                 Wt_max=c(61,NA,63,63),
                 Wt_min=c(60,NA,63,62),
                 Ht_avg=c(173.5,174.5,173,173.667),
                 Ht_max=c(174,175,173,174),
                 Ht_min=c(173,174,173,173))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `across` to get apply the same function across multiple columns, and use a list to get multiple functions. Since some of your groups have only NAs, you should do an `ifelse` to get `NA` instead of `NaN` (and warning messages) in those cases.

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(id, yearmonthweek) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Wt, Ht), list(avg = ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                                   min = ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, min(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                                   max = ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))))
```

```r
     id yearmonthweek Wt_avg Wt_min Wt_max Ht_avg Ht_min Ht_max
1     1       2012052   60.5     60     61   174.    173    174
2     1       2012053   NA       NA     NA   175     175    175
3     2       2012051   63       63     63   173     173    173
4     2       2012052   62.3     62     63   174.    173    174
```

You can also use this `soft` function which removes this issue:

```r
soft <- function(x, f, ...) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, f(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...))

data %>% 
  group_by(id, yearmonthweek) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Wt, Ht), list(avg = ~ soft(.x, mean),
                                   min = ~ soft(.x, min),
                                   max = ~ soft(.x, max))))
```